# error:‘String’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type std::String isAble(long D, int T, int B)

Tags: c++, string

```
#include < string.h >
class LongLongTripDiv2
{
public:
    std::string isAble(long D, int T, int B)
    {
       //....
       //...
    }
};
```

The above code gives an error: ‘String’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type std::String isAble(long D, int T, int B)
I have tried everything "using namespace std" and "using std::string but it still doesn't works.

Comment: it is `std::string` not `std::String`

Comment: Also it should be `#include <string>`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It is good practice but I dont think it will matter, because how #include "" works

Comment: do read about string 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4k49tt9.aspx

Comment: Unless `"string"` finds something different first, it will act like `<string>`. That said, the latter is really much more common for standard headers. Now with the edit, `string.h` is most certainly not the same thing.

Comment: @Creris it does effect the search path used. `#include "string.h"` can be overridden by a "string.h" in the same folder as the source file.

Comment: so this problem is because string.h header does not declare std::string, it is a C header, which contains the Cstring functions(strlen etc) afaik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your include statement is wrong.

```
#include <string>

class LongLongTripDiv2
{
public:
    std::string isAble(long D, int T, int B);
};
```